# Android preference activity windowed and not full screen

Tags: android, xml, preference

I have a preference activity that does the norm addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences) & setContentView(R.layout.preferencelayout)...  Everything works fine.

What I need to do is open that same preference screen as a window (like an alert dialog) and not a full screen.

Anyone know how?

EDIT: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" Fixes this, but any custom preferences (in this case a slider) is not displayed any more.

EDIT2:  android_hungry's response fixes this issue to a point.  Custom preferences now work, but the suggestion below now makes a solid black background and not a true dialog look.  For the time being, this works.  Please post an answer so I can accept it for you.

Comment: What do you mean slider? ScrollView?

Comment: just try removing dialog theme , and add this to root element of ur layout `android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"`